# Group homomorphism between quotient groups.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups, group-homomorphism, quotient-group

Let $G$ and $H$ be two groups and $M, N$ be normal subgroups of $G$ and $H$ respectively. Consider a relation $\phi: G \to H$ be a homomorphism.
Now, my question is

> what is the necessary condition on $\phi$ such that it induces a homomorphism between $\frac{G}{M}$ and $\frac{H}{N}.$

Comment: It doesn't make sense to define a map $gM\mapsto gN$ since $g$ is an element of the group $G$, but not $H$.

Comment: @Levent I have changed this sir.

Comment: but now it's even more puzzling. You ask if this homomorphism is well defined, I ask which homomorphism?

Comment: It is still wrong, if it's a map it's well-defined.

Comment: @Levent sorry for the problem, now please have a look on it.

Comment: If you "let $\phi$ be a map from $G/M$ to $H/N$" then $\phi$ is already (well) defined. What is missing is that $\phi$ is a homomorphism.

Comment: *A* necessary and sufficient condition for $\phi\colon G/M\to H/N$ to be a homomorphism is that $\phi(xy^{-1})=\phi(x)\phi(y)^{-1}$ for all $x,y\in G/M$,

Comment: As always:  $\phi(\bar{x}\bar{y})=\phi(\bar{x})\phi(\bar{y})$.

Comment: You ask when $\phi$ becomes a homomorphism without giving what $\phi$ is.

Comment: I suspect that you are really wanting to ask something like this: Let $f:G\to H$ be a homomorphism of groups. Let $\pi_1:G\to G/M$ and $\pi_2: H\to H/N$ be the usual projections. Under what conditions is there a homomorphism $\phi: G/M\to H/N$ such that $\phi \circ \pi_1=\pi_2\circ f$. Then your "answer" could be modified to make good sense.

Comment: $\phi$ is a relation, now my question is there any bundation on $\phi, N ,M$ to make  $\phi$ a homomorphism

Comment: This is a mess; if $\phi$ is defined on $G/M$ with target $H/N$, then a necessary and sufficient condition for $\phi$ to be a homomorphism is that it be a function and be multiplicative, just like any function between two groups. I suspect that is **not** what you want. Perhaps you want a function (homomorphism?) $\phi\colon G\to H$, and then you want to try to define an **induced** function $\overline{\phi}\colon \frac{G}{M}\to \frac{H}{N}$ by $\overline{\phi}(gM) = \phi(g)N$, and what to know what is needed for this to be (well-defined and) a homomorphism?

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Yes sir my question is this, I know sir for this it should be well defined. But can we more precisely that what needed to make it well defined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The map $\pi\circ \phi\colon G\to H/N$ factors through $G/M$ if and only if $M\subseteq \mathrm{ker}(\pi\circ\phi)$. The kernel of $\pi\circ\phi$ is $\phi^{-1}(\ker(\pi)) = \phi^{-1}(N)$.

So a necessary and sufficient condition is $M\subseteq \phi^{-1}(N)$.